# How to run momentJs with two languages or duplicate moment()?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I need two instances of momentJs with slightly different language settings and tried this [according to the documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/instance-language/):

```
var moment2 = moment();
moment2.lang('en', { ... });
```

Where is the moment("2014-05-22") function in moment2?

I need something like this:

```
moment2("2014-05-22").calendar();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution that really works. It overwrites momentJs's global language setting on every calendar() call.

```
moment.lang('de');

// internationalisation objects for momentJs calendar view WITHOUT time:
var momentShort = {
    'de': {
        calendar : {
            sameDay: "[heute]",
            sameElse: "L",
            nextDay: '[morgen]',
            nextWeek: 'dddd',
            lastDay: '[gestern]',
            lastWeek: '[letzten] dddd'
        }
    },
    'en' : {
        calendar : {
            sameDay : '[today]',
            nextDay : '[tomorrow]',
            nextWeek : 'dddd',
            lastDay : '[yesterday]',
            lastWeek : '[last] dddd',
            sameElse : 'L'
        }
    }
};

// internationalisation objects for momentJs calendar view WITH time:
var momentFull = {
    'de': {
        calendar : {
            sameDay: "[heute um] LT",
            sameElse: "L",
            nextDay: '[morgen um] LT',
            nextWeek: 'dddd [um] LT',
            lastDay: '[gestern um] LT',
            lastWeek: '[letzten] dddd [um] LT'
        },
    },
    'en' : {
        calendar : {
            sameDay : '[today at] LT',
            nextDay : '[tomorrow at] LT',
            nextWeek : 'dddd [at] LT',
            lastDay : '[yesterday at] LT',
            lastWeek : '[last] dddd [at] LT',
            sameElse : 'L'
        }
    }
};


moment.lang(moment.lang(), momentShort[moment.lang()]);
var cal = moment("2014-05-23");
console.log( cal.calendar() );


moment.lang(moment.lang(), momentLong[moment.lang()]);
var cal = moment("2014-05-23");
console.log( cal.calendar() );
```

Comment: This is a good workaround to the issue I just pointed out, glad you found it.

Answer (score 2):

`moment.lang` provides **instance specific configuration**, so you do not set it relatively to the factory function, but to the single moment instance.

I think you should do something like:

```
var local = moment('2014-05-22');
local.lang('fr', { calendar : {
  lastDay : '[new]',
  sameDay : '[new]',
  nextDay : '[new]',
  lastWeek : '[new]',
  nextWeek : '[new]',
  sameElse : '[new]'
}});
console.log(local.calendar());
```

The result:

```
"vendredi à 00:00"
```

It is french, but it should be "new".

### Update

The code above will not work because momentjs doesn't allow to patch an existing language to define your own calendar. You have to set a new language. They really need to point this out in the documentation. [See this issue on github](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1569)

Comment: This does not work. You can set 'fr', but the 'calendar' object will be ignored.

Comment: Strange, I looked at the [calendar section](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/calendar/) of the docs and this is what they (seem to) do.

Comment: Stupid question: are you using a version of moment >= 1.3.0?

Comment: Yes. The current version 2.6.0

Comment: Do you need custom calendar formatting? Otherwise you could use the provided `moment-with-langs.js` which has everything already included and works: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/simonedavico/cwqq3/)

Comment: I need two different outputs of calendar(). With time and sometimes just the date.

Comment: Why not use `moment-with-langs` and create the two instances as specified above/in the docs, without having to care about formatting `calendar` yourself? [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/simonedavico/cwqq3/1/).

Comment: And where are the two flavours of calendar() now?

Comment: If you looked the console you would see that one message is printed in english, while the other in french. If this is not what you were looking for, then I misunderstood your question.

Comment: I need the output of calendar() with time and without time. But the same language.

Comment: I just found the 'solution' to the problem among momentjs' github issue tracker. It seems like it's not working because you cannot overwrite the calendar specification of an existing language, as we were trying to do with `fr`. I assume it should be enough to "make up a new language name" to solve the issue. [Link to issue](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1569)